# Find line + 1 line after it

Tags: regex, multiline

How to find line + one line after that?

Eg
I have the lines

```
123123
some text
546454
some text
354543
some text
465466
some text
123123
some text
```

So i know how to find 123123 (^123123) and other but how get +1 line with text 'some text'

result shoud be

```
123123
some text
123123
some text
```

**Update**

I forgot to say, after text can be other text 123123 is start of line

```
123123 text text text text text
some text
```

Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a new line between your pattern and related regex for next line :

```
/123123\n[^\d]+/g
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/zA2cU6/1

Note that `[^\d]+` will match any combination of characters which doesn't contains digit.(you can change it based on your need)

Update:

If you want to match the text after your pattern you just can add `.*` after it :

```
123123.*\n[^\d]+
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/zA2cU6/2

Comment: @user2483213 You too ;-)